# AngularJs: UI bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Could you please help me with the ui bootstrap tooltip in angular. On hovering over button details I need to show a table. Greatly appreciate the help. Thanks.

HTML:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['pinnacaServices','ngMaterial', 'ui.router', 'ncy-angular-breadcrumb', 'md.data.table', 'anim-in-out','ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
              <td md-cell >
                     <button >Details</button>
              </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepare file with your html structure, use ui tooltip as directive. It can be something like this.

```
<button uib-tooltip-template="'myTooltipTemplate.html'">Details</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use scope variable and `uib-tooltip-html` to show table on tooltip

Sample is [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/V8ycZGgbufsjgLNb78bS?p=preview)